# How to export multiple microservices jaeger metrics stored in elasticsearch to prometheus

Tags: elasticsearch, prometheus, jaeger

We are able to get latency metrics of multiple microservices using Jaeger.  Currently Jaeger stores application metrics in elasticsearch.

My usecase is to get the latency of application from elasticsearch to prometheus.

Is there anyway to read the elasticsearch metrics of Jaeger? I already used elasticsearch-prometheus-exporter which only exports cluster details of ES.

Answer (score 1):

The prometheus-es-exporter provides a way to create metrics using queries.

For further details you can check [prometheus-es-exporter#query-metrics](https://github.com/braedon/prometheus-es-exporter#query-metrics)